# Trouble installing meteor on mac

Tags: macos, meteor, installation

When I run the command given on the meteor website:

curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh

I get as follows:

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: meteorinstall-4168.kxcdn.com

when I run:

ping meteorinstall-4168.kxcdn.com

I get:

```
Request timeout for icmp_seq 30
64 bytes from 161.202.39.238: icmp_seq=31 ttl=51 time=182.303 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 32
64 bytes from 161.202.39.238: icmp_seq=33 ttl=51 time=181.406 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 34
Request timeout for icmp_seq 35
64 bytes from 161.202.39.238: icmp_seq=36 ttl=51 time=186.054 ms
64 bytes from 161.202.39.238: icmp_seq=37 ttl=51 time=182.544 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 38
64 bytes from 161.202.39.238: icmp_seq=39 ttl=51 time=186.920 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 40
```

What should I do?

Comment: This is a network issue. Are you using any VPNs or proxies? Maybe try changing your DNS settings to use Google's DNS servers 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4

Comment: thanks,I change to VPN,the problem resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If you try again, this should work now. Meteor 1.4.1.1 was accidentally not published properly before the 1.4.1.1 release number was recommended. New downloads were broken until sometime yesterday (you can see the full details in [issue 7697](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7697)).